# TypeError: test.describe is not a function when using nodejs, selenium and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I am getting TypeError: test.describe is not a function when using 'test' with describe, it, before etc.

Using node, selenium and mocha to run tests.

Please find the code below:

Test that I am executing:

```
 var LoginObj = require('../pages/Login.js');
 var HomeObj = require('../pages/Home.js');
 var LoginData = require('../testdata/LoginData.json');
 var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');
 var basetest = require('../pages/BaseTest.js');
 var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing')
 var driver = basetest.getDriver();

 test.describe('Checking  Login Functionality', function() {

 test.beforeEach(function(){
    driver.get('https://applicationurl.com');
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);

 });

 LoginData.forEach(function(data, username, password) {
 test.it('Login with: '+data.username+" and "+data.password, function() {

    //LoginObj.get();

    LoginObj.login(data.username, data.password, data.answer);

    assert.isTrue(HomeObj.isLogoutDisplays(),'Login successful, Passing 
     Test!')
     console.log('Login flag is: '+HomeObj.isLogoutDisplays()+', Failing 
     Test!');



   })

    });

   test.afterEach(function() {

        HomeObj.logout();


    }) 

 });
```

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this issue? I have been stuck with the same problem for a while. the problem seems to be a package reference issue but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This kind of usage has been deprecated actually. You just need to use describe only and make sure you have imported and installed all required packages from npm like mocha, chai (if using this) etc and call them in your JS file. You may check my repository here for reference www.githhub.com/rohinegi548

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mocha you will not need this:

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing')
```

Just remove the 'test' from 'test.describe' and it will work.

So it should be:

```
describe('Checking  Login Functionality', function() {

   beforeEach(function(){
    driver.get('https://applicationurl.com');
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);

 });
```